# Error importing requests into python

Tags: python, eclipse, api, import, pydev

I am writing a Merchant Data Export API in Python (Pydev plugin for eclipse) and I cannot import requests, is there some option for managing imports?
I have the requests-master folder in my project, downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/requests/requests). I have read the following [articles](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for [downloading](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/)and [installing](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python), but nothing works for me.

I am a new python user but would like to learn more. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just do a `pip install requests`, things should work (the issue is that you probably aren't adding the proper folder to the PYTHONPATH for PyDev to recognize the `requests` module you downloaded... using `pip` should do the right thing for you without requiring further configurations).